# How to register custom control in web.config file

Tags: asp.net

I have one custom control. I add reference to it on ASPX pages like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cus" Namespace="Controls" %>
```

at run time there is no error.

Error shown at deploy time

> Unknown server tag
>   'cus:GridHeaderFilter'.

My custom control is in App_Code folder with name `GridHeaderFilter.vb`

So how to add or register this custom control in `web.config` file

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the classname and the namespace are correct. Also the class is public. Ideally the settings you have should work.
Registring it in web.config is fairly simple and similar.

Check this: [Registering control in web.config](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/14/register_custom_controls_in_web.config.aspx).